# parsing a JSON response using JSON.NET and arrays & LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm wanting to return the address information from my linq response. I'm close but just can't get the last bit. I'm needing all the address information from each entry.

Can someone assist with the last bit please?

```
  var allCentres = from p in obj["early_child_centres"]
            select p["address"].Children ();

            foreach (var item in allCentres)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

 {

"early_child_centres": [
{

  "centre_name": "Arncliffe Early Childhood Centre",

  "address": {
    "street_name": "12 Firth St",
    "suburb": "Arncliffe",
    "state": "NSW",
    "postcode": "2205",
    "phone": "9599 2896"
  },
  "special_notes": "",

},

]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a entity to deserialize your json :

```
[DataContract]
public class Center
{
    [DataMember(Name = "center_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "special_notes")]
    public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Center() { this.Address = new Address();}
}

[DataContract]
public class Address
{
    [DataMember(Name = "street_name")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "suburb")]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "postcode")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize with :

```
List<Center> centers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Center>>(obj["early_child_centres"].ToString());
```

And then, your linq request :

```
from c in center
select c.Address
```

Comment: Hi Joffrey, thank you for providing such a concise and complete answer for me. It worked like a treat.